# Ansible: repeated lines exists but update only specific occurrence

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have to change

```
`<!--<parameter name=\"HostnameVerifier\">DefaultAndLocalhost</parameter>-->`
```

to 
    `<!--<parameter name=\"HostnameVerifier\">AllowAll</parameter>-->` in APIM_HOME/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml.

I am using

`- name: "Modify HostnameVerifier"
          lineinfile:
            dest: "/home/ec2-user/ansible-test/wso2am-2.0.0/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml"
            state: "present"
            line: "\t\t<parameter name=\"HostnameVerifier\">AllowAll</parameter>"
            regexp: "<!--<parameter name=\"HostnameVerifier\">DefaultAndLocalhost</parameter>-->"`

This is only replacing the 3rd occurrence of the regexp. I want it to replace only 2nd occurrence. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with `lineinfile`. From the [docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/lineinfile_module.html):

> ...only the last line found will be replaced...

And `lineinfile` iterates line-by-line – you can't add more context to it.

You should use [replace](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/replace_module.html) module and add more context to the regexp to match exatly that part of file you want to modify. You can use multiline patterns here.

Comment: I did tried with replace, some how not able to get to the desired output